# jquery offset method doesn't seem to return whole numbers

Tags: jquery

When using jquery's offset method on an element to get its top offset from the document, it returns me the following for example:

```
1150.3999938964844
```

Is there a reason why it does that, and doesn't return a whole number?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it has any dimensions defined as percentages (or any parent does really, unless it's out of the flow) for instance....there's no guarantee it's a whole number :)

Comment: All widths/heights have been declared as pixels, guess I can use math.round to eliminate this. Odd though. Thanks

Comment: @Rishi - Do you have an example page I can see?, I could tell you where it's coming from then.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a reason why it does that,
>   and doesn't return a whole number?

```
jQuery.fn.offset = function( options ) {

...

parseFloat( ... )

...
```

- jQuery source

See also: [Floating Point Accuracy Problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems) at Wikipedia